# How to implement seek functionality on videos with fastapi

Tags: python, html, rest, fastapi

I am designing a website using fastapi on Python and on one the pages I want to show a video.
This is my test.py code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/")
async def read_root(request: Request):
    video_url = '/static/videos/test.mp4'
    return templates.TemplateResponse("edit.html", {"request": request,'video_url':video_url})
```

and here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TESTING</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="600" height="300" controls>
        <source src="{{ video_url }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

One of the features I want is video seeking. If I try to display video without fastapi, seeking works perfect but with fastapi it doesn't. Can anyone suggest me solution?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  The web browser doesn't know what's generating the HTML.    If you hardcode `/static/videos/test.mp4` in the HTML, does that work?

Comment: This is just a testing file. Once it starts working here i will integrate to main project.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: My bad. Yes if I hard code it on HTML page, it works fine. All functionalities work. But with fastapi I can't use seeking functionality for video

Comment: You might see if this answers the question:  https://stribny.name/blog/fastapi-video/